# PHP Textarea append

Tags: php, html, css

OK let's say I have a textarea and I type in that textarea

```
Hello my name is
Frank and I like
to eat apples.
```

then when I hit submit button I get:

```
[Hello my name is]
[Frank and I like]
[to eat apples.]
```

See how every line is appended at the start and end with brackets?

Is there a way you can even do this in PHP?

Comment: Are you saying that you want that behavior?

Comment: I'm asking if it is possible to split up every line in a textarea and append it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes:

```
$output = '['.str_replace("\n", "]\n[", $input).']';
```

I'm not sure if a textarea sends `\n` or `\r\n`. If its the latter, just change `\n` to `\r\n` in the above.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest (and fastest) way to do this is via a string replace. Assuming a "message" textarea:

```
$text = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : '';
$text = str_replace("\n\r", "\n", $text);
$text = str_replace("\r", "\n", $text);
$text = "[" . str_replace("\n", "]\n[", $text) . "]";
echo $text;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve spacing then you have to use regular expressions:

```
$_POST['textarea'] = '['.preg_replace('!((?:\n|\r)+)!', "]$1[", trim($_POST['textarea'])).']';
```

Comment: my advice (always) is to munge raw input data into a known format, maybe call it a standard for your application. then, you can reformat it as appropriate for output requirements.

Comment: Not quite sure what that comment means? I just added a method that would preserve multiple newlines between lines with text rather than leaving blank lines with [] on them. I'm pretty certain that the output is no more or less a 'known format' in either case! str_replace is far faster if that's all that's needed though, I agree.

Comment: I mean that software should have data integrity, including newline structure. Not saying preg isn't a good idea, but just explaining the reason for a data-cleaning approach.